# Pivot to wide and keep all columns

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr, transpose

I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), B=c(3,3,3,6,6, 6), C=c(2,3,9,12,2, 6), D=c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a1", "a2", "a3"))
```

and i want a dataset like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a1=c(2,12), a2=c(3, 2), a3=c(9, 6), B=c(3,6))
```

I try this function but it doesn't work:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(B = if_else(B == 1, "A", "B")) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  mutate(var = paste0("V",row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = B, names_from = var, values_from = A) %>% 
  rename(row_name = B)
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider`. To keep the column "B", use `unused_fn` with a summarizing function (here, `mean`, but it could also be `first`, `min`, `max`...).

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(A, names_from = D, values_from = C, unused_fn = mean)
```

```r
      A    a1    a2    a3     B
1     1     2     3     9     3
2     2    12     2     6     6
```

Answer (score 2):

data.table provides a nice function *dcast* (pass from reahspe2) to make this happen:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(df, A + B ~ D, value.var = "C")
```

```
  A B a1 a2 a3
1 1 3  2  3  9
2 2 6 12  2  6
```

[Read this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) if interested